# Table rows not fitting the <tbody> width

Tags: css, html-table

In a HTML table, I have to set `display: block;` property to `tbody` in order to make `tbody` scrollable vertically. My issue is that when I add this property, the width of the rows `<tr>` is not fitting `tbody` width anymore. It seems like `width: 100%;` is not taken into account anymore for the rows...

I want to set a `' absolute width (e.g. 300px) and inside this table, set a 100% width to the rows so that the rows fit the table width.

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/wiltomap/0fnLhujn/.

Here are my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00f;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

tbody {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Species</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Locality</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>6</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>7</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>9</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you changed `tbody` from table to block, you need to make now the `tr` to table

```
tr{
    display: table;
}
```

**See code snippet:**

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00f;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

tbody {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Species</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Locality</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>6</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>7</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>9</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td><td>Erithacus rubecula</td><td>2001-05-05</td><td>Manchester, UK</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I notice the table headers aren't aligned with the body - can you fix that?

Comment: @CalvT븃 you will need javascript to align the cells of tbody with cells of thead ... example here http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/CrSpu/555/

Comment: @Chiller I've been looking at that exact fiddle for a minute now :D

Comment: @CalvT븃 i had to search for it too XD